# Can I set delay in Redis Pub/Sub?

Tags: node.js, redis

In redis, I subscribed someone channel, when I publish to this channel, I want to receive messages after a delay I set , can I do that ? (I mean, althougth I can do that in my app through setTimeout in node.js, I want to do that just through redis itself)

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. Redis PubSub messages are sent immediately once the `PUBLISH` command is processed by the server.